# Is it possible to have a completely statically linked GUI app on Linux?

Tags: linux, user-interface, static-linking

Is it possible to have a completely statically linked GUI app on Linux? I'm aware that some libraries (e.g. Qt5) have the option to be statically compiled and linked into the executable, but even then the resulting executable is dynamically linked to other libraries.

If it is possible, is there a reference project which demonstrates how it's done? If it's not, why is this so?

Note: I'm deliberately leaving out the question of programming languages, gui libraries/frameworks, or GUI architectures (webview/native desktop) to broaden the scope for answers.

Comment: This would only be practical with a system that had a dedicated application program that exclusively acquired the framebuffer/display and input devices, e.g. an embedded system.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for this. I find it somewhat confusing that any other class of peripherals (i.e. disk drives, network cards, etc.) are managed by the kernel such that a static executable does not need any drivers or other device-specific code to work with these devices. Do you know why the graphics card (and the graphics software stack I suppose) is treated differently here?

Comment: Storage drives and network adapters are accessed through filesystems and protocol stacks implemented in the kernel that present a multi-user interface. The graphical interface in Linux (and UNIX) is an optional device & interface, and traditionally does not have a similar kernel-based multi-user interface. I don't have an answer as to "why" the GUI is implemented in userspace, although the new DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) could help change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For wayland and X at least, client and server communicate over unix socket. There usually exists a client-side library (usually dynamically linked), which abstracts this low-level communication. And it can be statically linked.
But clients do not need to be linked with server library. Still you have to run display server (or compositor in wayland terms).
Technically, you don't even need any client-side libraries and could implement low-level communication scheme yourself (similarly, you don't need a browser to use HTTP protocol, but can write it manually).

There is a [wayland client library](https://github.com/rajveermalviya/go-wayland) written in pure Go. Go uses dynamic linking only when including C libraries, which this library does not do. You can install the example programs and verify they are statically linked.

I also managed to statically build a [simple application](https://github.com/Kljunas2/static-wayland), also for wayland.